# waiting for richtext update

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

i'm doing a simple application like a news portal. main.mxml is displaying short views of the each news via the newsRenderer.mxml. when user click on any one, full content of the news will open on the main.mxml.
i'm using richtext component for the full content. i can get the index of the clicked news from newsRenderer and assign it to richtext as below code.

*newsRenderer.mxml*

```
        private function choosen():void
        {
            borderContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, send, false, 0);
        }
        public function send(event:Event):void{
            FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.index = data.id; //news id
        }
```

*main.mxml*

```
internal var index:int; 

protected function richText_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        getNewsByIDResult.token = newsService.getNewsByID(index);
    }

<s:RichText id="richText" includeIn="fullContent" left="20" right="20" top="50"
            creationComplete="richText_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
            text="{getNewsByIDResult.lastResult.content}"/>
```

problem is that, when user opened a news after another, it is displaying old news content or it is updated after one second. how can i force the richtext to wait for the end of updating. i could not find any event listener about this.

Answer (score 1):

There are no event listener for a custom business rule (ie. load content before showing).  I guess you could use VALUE_COMMIT or something, but personally I would just rethink the flow of your application:

1. Get all articles with id and short blurb
2. Show all articles with blurb in item renderer
3. Item renderer listens for user click and retrieves rest of article from server (showing loading animation)
4. After data is returned, update text and resize to show content to user

Comment: yes, this flow is exactly what i doing. the question is that how can i notice when the loading completed.
i couldn't solve it with valuecommit yet.

Comment: Well, if you're loading *anything*, you'll have a result event/function to get your data.